# passing URL parameter with Turkish characters

Tags: jquery, asp.net, urlencode

I am sending a request to a web service from jQuery with Turkish characters. Before I send it from jQuery, I `encodeURI` the Turkish String, and try to decode it in a web service in C#. But that doesn't work.

Here is the jQuery code

```
  $.ajax({url: 'http://xxxxxx.com/medbul/HoverCard_WebService.aspx?q=' + encodeURI(span_text),
```

Here is the code in web service

```
  HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["q"].ToString())
```

But that doesn't work. Any way to do this?

What I mean is If I pass English characters, it does what it is supposed to do, but when I pass Turkish characters, It doesnt show the result. I am not showing the all code because not necessary.  I think I have  a problem with encoding in Javascript and Decoding in C#. Or Should I use another logic?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: I added some explanation above. I hope it is clear now

Comment: Does nothing show up at all when you use turkish characters? Do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you won to send UTF-8 as your language from the URL, the correct is to use the `encodeURIComponent`

So change your code to

```
$.ajax({url: 'http://xxxxxx.com/medbul/HoverCard_WebService.aspx?q=' + encodeURIComponent(span_text),
```

and it will work.

[Comparing escape(), encodeURI(), and encodeURIComponent()](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/)

Comment: it doesnt work. I put alert(encodeURIComponent(span_text)) and I can see it encodes perfectly, but HoverCard_WebService.aspx doesnt return any value

Comment: @Borsel Yes its work, I use it. I check now again some details and replay you again.

Comment: @Borsel I can not find any obvious issue, I belive that you need to make some small tests and see what is breaking it (even change the ', with " on the url). Alternative you can make 'post' and send them on the data parameter and not direct to the url. If you like I can post you the code.

Comment: yeah you are right. But now I habe a differen problem with the database. Wheren I do a regular Select * from Categories where catname like '%Göğüs%' It doesnt return anything. I think I have to do something with the DB